# Why doesn't my jekyll github site have styles?

Tags: css, git, github, rubygems, jekyll

This is my repository: https://github.com/attilay/jeky

How my website should look like and the repository of theme: http://themes.jekyllrc.org/linear/

My website doesn't load any styling, just plain HTML.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in `_layouts/default.html`, include `{{ site.baseurl }}` in the relative paths to `assets` in your `head` (as David Jacquel suggests):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/skel-noscript.css" />
```

and

```
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/js/init.js"></script>
```

In addition, in `/assets/js/init.js` change:

```
prefix: '/assets/css/style',
```

to

```
prefix: '{{site.baseurl}}/assets/css/style',
```

and, finally, in order for Jekyll to process `init.js` and insert the baseurl, add

```
---
---
```

at the top of the file as empty YML frontmatter.

Answer (score 0):

In your `_layouts/default.html`, You must call your assets with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/skel-noscript.css" />
```

or

```
 <script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/js/init.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm.. I applied {{ site.baseurl }}/(folder) to all the links and scripts. Something changed but it still doesn't look right :(